# The Python shell is telling me it is invalid syntax

Tags: if-statement, syntax

```
if guess == answer:
    print("Correct!")
    score + 1
elif:
    print("Incorrect")
else:
    except ValueError:
        print("Expected integer")
```

That was a small section of my code. It states that `elif:` is invalid, specifically the `:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where is the condition for elif: place any condition to check it

```
if guess == answer:
    print("Correct!")
    score + 1
elif #condition :
    print("Incorrect")
else:
    except ValueError:
    print("Expected integer")
```

[REFERENCE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `elif` statement.

```
elif guess == <something>:
```

Answer (score 1):

after elif you have to write an expression. For example:
 `elif guess == question:
      print("Incorrect")`